# Ruby: attr_accessor method undefined when called in an outside module

Tags: ruby

I have a ruby class defined in a module as shown below

```
module Foo
    class Bar
        attr_accessor :attr_1, :attr_2, :attr_3

        def initialize
            @attr_1 = "a"
            @attr_2 = "b"
            @attr_3 = "c"
        end

    end
end
```

I am then trying to access the instance variables (or the getters defined by attr_accessor) in a seperate module as shown below:

```
module AccessingModule

    def get_instance_variables
        var_1 = Foo::Bar.attr_1
        var_2 = Foo::Bar.attr_2
        var_3 = Foo::Bar.attr_3

    end

 end
```

When trying to call `var_1 = Foo::Bar.attr_1` I get the error `NoMethodError: undefined method attr_1 for Foo::Bar:Class`

Does anyone know what is preventing me from accessing what is defined in the attr_accessor?

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning instance variables in your `initialize` method. But in the module you try to call class methods on `Foo::Bar`.

You need to create the instance of `Foo::Bar` first and call the getter methods on the instance then:

```
module AccessingModule
  def get_instance_variables
    foo_bar = Foo::Bar.instance # get the Singleton instance of `Foo::Bar`

    var_1 = foo_bar.attr_1
    var_2 = foo_bar.attr_2
    var_3 = foo_bar.attr_3
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you for the comment. @spickermann I left a similar comment below, but when I try to instantiate Foo::Bar I receive the error `cannot access private method new`

Comment: I cannot reproduce that `Foo::Bar.new` with the class from the example raises such an error. There is nothing in the code that makes that method private. Are you sure that your example includes all relevant code?

Comment: Two things I left out are that Foo::Bar includes Singleton and module AccessingModule extends ActiveSupport::Concern. Would those two things make a difference?

Comment: Yes, it does. Because `include Singleton` makes the `new` method private. You have to use `instance` instead of `new` to get the one singleton instance instead of creating new (different) instances with `new` each time in this case. See: [`How to Use The Singleton Pattern`](https://www.rubyguides.com/2018/05/singleton-pattern-in-ruby/). I updated my answer to address this.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to access instance variables without instantiating a `Foo::Bar` object. First create an instance of `Foo::Bar`, then you can access `attr_1`, `attr_2`...

```rb
bar = Foo::Bar.new

bar.attr_1 # => 'a'
```

Now, if you want to access the attributes without instantiating an object, you need to define them as class variables:

```
module Foo
  class Bar
    @@attr_1 = 'a'

    def self.attr_1
      @@attr_1
    end
  end
end

Foo::Bar.attr_1 # => 'a'
```

If you don't know what instance and class variables are, read [this post](http://www.railstips.org/blog/archives/2006/11/18/class-and-instance-variables-in-ruby/).

Comment: Thank you for the reply. When I try to instantiate a new object I get hit with the error that I `cannot access private method new`.

Comment: @samiam0906 The code you posted works for me. Is that all your code?

Comment: Two things I left out are that Foo::Bar includes Singleton and module AccessingModule extends ActiveSupport::Concern. Would those two things make a difference?

Comment: @samiam0906 I'm not very familiar with Singleton, but I know it does raise a `NoMethodError: private method 'new' called for Foo::Bar` and it's considered an anti-pattern. Are you sure you need to use this?

Comment: when I remove the Singleton inclusion I am able to call new on the class. The class I am trying to create is supposed to be a Singleton, but maybe there is a workaround without using the Singleton declaration.

Comment: @samiam0906 If you **really need** to use Singleton, you'll have to call methods like this: `Foo::Bar.instance.attr_1`. But that's ugly. You could define everything as class methods and access them like this: `Foo::Bar.attr_1`.